# Rooting Xperia Play 2.3.4 without unlocking bootloader

Tags: rooting, sony-ericsson-xperia-play

After reading many forums, just came across this site. I may sound outdated, but I want to root my Xperia play. After reading many forums. I am confused.

I have an unlocked Xperia Play 2.3.4 build 4.0.2.A.0.42 (not locked to operator). Can I root it with SuperOneClick latest version 2.3.3 ??

I want to root Xperia Play for saving internal space. I don't want to unlock bootloader.

Will I lose all my messages, contacts, settings, etc by rooting?

Please guide me with links to the software for rooting if possible.

Comment: After doing a quick search, I found on a thread that you have to downgrade to 2.3.3 to root it. And yes, that **could** erase your messages. I suggest you make backups of them.

Comment: You can backup your contacts, settings etc. with TitaniumBackup. It's a local backup though, you might want to dish out money for the pro version so you can backup to Dropbox/Google Drive etc.

Comment: I didn't even realize it was possible to root without unlocking the bootloader.